# Creating a link in ReactJS that will go to the Django admin site

Tags: reactjs, django

I am looking for a way to link the Django admin site from ReactJS. Initially the domain of Django admin site is '127.0.0.1/admin' but the domain '127.0.0.1' will eventually change. Is there a way to make a dynamic code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Works with creating a function that will capture the hostname using `window.location.hostname` with the URL

```
const goToAdmin = () => {
  const domain = "http://" + window.location.host + ":8080/admin"
  window.open(domain, '_blank) // If you want to open domain in new window
}
```

Then call the function in an `onClick`

```
<p onClick={goToAdmin}>Admin Site</p>
```